# How to type command locally when using ssh?

Tags: ssh

When I connect to a server via very slow network, it will be very slow to type commands as whenever I type a character it will not show up immediately on the screen. Is there a way to type the command as if it is locally, until I type Enter the ssh client will not try to communicate with the remote server? Only when I type Enter, the client then send the whole command to the server at once. Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: Could you help migrate the question there?

Comment: Quick answer: `mosh`

Comment: mosh requires opening an additional port, which I can not do it for now. Anything that does not reiqure opening an additional port?